# Android emulator not working (Genymotion)

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

My built-in emulator cannot be used in Android Studio because it says my laptop does not support its recommended graphics.

Which emulator should I install? I have installed Genymotion but it shows that ip address is missing.

Comment: Can you show an image of the error it gives you on Genymotion?

As for Android Studio, make sure you have HAXM installed.

Comment: for `GenyMotion` please install `VirtualBox` first and check your CPU's `Virtualization` support

Comment: Yes, I've installed Oracle Virtual Genymotion.

Comment: make sure `Virtualization Extension` is enabled in bios

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'll try it. Mark.jon